# How do I get pages to have Roman numerals? How can I move a table to the left when flushleft won't work?

Tags: tables, page-numbering

1. How do I get pages to have Roman numerals?
2. How can I move a table to the left when flushleft won't work?

Comment: Do you have some example code (in the form of a code snippet, or preferably an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)) that illustrates why (2) doesn't work?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please only have one question per question post. Please remove the second one here and post it as an own question. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You can typeset the page numbers in Roman numerals using one of the following two ways. Either use

```
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\Roman{page}}
```

or

```
\pagenumbering{Roman}
```

in your document preamble. The latter command [`\pagenumbering` is defined as follows](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx):

```
\def\pagenumbering#1{%
  \global\c@page \@ne \gdef\thepage{\csname @#1\endcsname \c@page}}
```

This sets the page counter to one globally (`\global\c@page \@ne`) and then defines the page counter typesetting/output `\thepage` to be the command sequence formatting of whatever is supplied in argument `#1` (`Roman` in this case).

Comment: Or `\pagenumbering{Roman}` in the document, which is actually better.